# Sum of special infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am not able to find sum of the infinite series:
$\sum_{(n=1)}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)}{n^2(n+1)^2}$
Can someone help me in solving this

Answer (score 2):

Break the fraction using partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{2n+1}{(n^2)(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

Now compute the series using a telescoping effect
which gives 
$$1-\frac{1}{(2)^2}+\frac1{(2)^2}...= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=1$$

Note:- This is possible as the series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}$ and you get a telescoping sum. The answer is therefore, $1+(1/2^2-1/2^2)+(1/3^2-1/3^2)+...=1$.

We are allowed to change the order we add the terms because the series is absolutely convergent.